# DOMSubtreeModified ... How to ensure it only fires once?

Tags: javascript

When using `DOMSubtreeModified` I get multiple, sometimes 30+ events firing. Is it possible to ensure that my function is only called once regardless of `DOMSubtreeModified` is fired?

Answer (score 6):

The [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) are performance hogs which can't really be tamed well. Therefore, they have been deprecated over a year ago and should be used only when really needed.

You could use the new and shiny [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) from DOM Level 4 (follow the links there!). Where `DOMSubtreeModified` fired a thousand times, `MutationObserver` fires only once with all the modifications contained and accessible.

Works for (as of 2012/06):

- Chrome 18+ (prefixed, `window.WebKitMutationObserver`)
- Firefox 14+ (unprefixed)
- WebKit nightlies

---

Other than that ... some hackish solution with removing the listener and scheduling to add it again in some time in future (a second or two) might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the eventListener after the function was called the first time.

Comment: I was deleting the listener, but I need to re-add it again. The script isn't loaded per page load as page requests are done using Ajax.